# Как сделать проверку на активного собеседника (анонимный чат)?

Tags: python, telegram-bot

Есть данный код, хочу сделать проверку на активного собеседника, на данный момент если собеседник завершил чат бот ждет 120с, что сильно замедляет его работу.

```
from telethon import TelegramClient
from telethon.tl.functions.messages import GetAllStickersRequest
from telethon.tl.functions.messages import GetStickerSetRequest
from telethon.tl.types import InputStickerSetID
import random
import time
import string



api_id = 'id'
api_hash = 'hash'

from telethon import TelegramClient, events
client = TelegramClient('Desktop', api_id, api_hash)
client.start()

@client.on(events.NewMessage)
async def my_event_handler(event):
    sticker_sets = await client(GetAllStickersRequest(0))
    sticker_set = sticker_sets.sets[0]
    stickers = await client(GetStickerSetRequest(
    stickerset=InputStickerSetID(
        id=sticker_set.id, access_hash=sticker_set.access_hash)))
 

    if 'Собеседник найден ' in event.raw_text: 
     await event.respond('Тест текст')
     time.sleep(120)
     await event.respond('/stop')
     time.sleep(0)   
 
@client.on(events.NewMessage)
async def my_event_handler(event):
    if 'Вы закончили связь с вашим собеседником ' in event.raw_text: 
        await event.respond('/next') 
    elif 'Собеседник закончил с вами связь ' in event.raw_text: 
        await event.respond('/next')
 

client.run_until_disconnected()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы применяете синхронный метод, в асинхронном процессе, что является неверным, т.к получается, что ждёт вся программа. Чтобы избежать этого сделайте вот так

```
from telethon import TelegramClient
from telethon.tl.functions.messages import GetAllStickersRequest
from telethon.tl.functions.messages import GetStickerSetRequest
from telethon.tl.types import InputStickerSetID
import random
import time
import string
import asyncio



api_id = 'id'
api_hash = 'hash'

from telethon import TelegramClient, events
client = TelegramClient('Desktop', api_id, api_hash)
client.start()

@client.on(events.NewMessage)
async def my_event_handler(event):
    sticker_sets = await client(GetAllStickersRequest(0))
    sticker_set = sticker_sets.sets[0]
    stickers = await client(GetStickerSetRequest(
    stickerset=InputStickerSetID(
        id=sticker_set.id, access_hash=sticker_set.access_hash)))
 

    if 'Собеседник найден ' in event.raw_text: 
     await event.respond('Тест текст')
     await asyncio.sleep(120) # +++
     await event.respond('/stop')
     await asyncio.sleep(0)  # +++
 
@client.on(events.NewMessage)
async def my_event_handler(event):
    if 'Вы закончили связь с вашим собеседником ' in event.raw_text: 
        await event.respond('/next') 
    elif 'Собеседник закончил с вами связь ' in event.raw_text: 
        await event.respond('/next')
 

client.run_until_disconnected()
```

Если помогло, то отметьте пожалуйста ответ верным.